# Finding a $ (3 \times 3) $-matrix that represents reflection across an arbitrary line $ y = m x + c $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reflection

I want to find a 3x3 Matrix that reflects in an Arbitrary Line y=mx+c
I have a matrix with me but it doesnt take into account the '$c$'

This is the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-m^2}{m^2+1}&     \frac{2m}{m^2+1}&         0 \\
\frac{2m}{m^2+1}&     \frac{m^2-1}{m^2+1}&     0 \\
  0&                           0&                  1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

The problem I have with this matrix is that i it reflects from the origin with the function $y=mx$
It doesnt take it in the $y-intercept$ factor.

So i would have to translate it to the origin then find the reflection using the above matrix then translate it back to the $y-intercept$

But is there **One** matrix that does everything. A 3x3 matrix that reflects in an arbitrary line $y=mx+c$. Which takes in all factors.

**Edit**
This is what Ive been working on. The matrix that reflects in an Aritrary Line
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR0q6.png)

But I cant seem to get the expected answer. Ive used matrix calculators online and ive done it manually and i dont know why im getting the wrong answer.
When i mean wrong answer. It means the negative symbols are there when they're not supposed to be.

This is the [Expected Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr9T5.png)

Below is the answer from a matrix calculator from online

tinyurl.com/n9njqfm

Comment: Do you know how to compose transformations that are represented as matrices? You’ve described a sequence of three transformations that do what you want. Now, combine them into one.

Comment: There cannot be one matrix that does this because in general, a reflection across a line is not linear. This is because linear functions must fix the origin. In the general case, the origin will get reflected across the line so the transformation will send $0$ to a non-zero value.

Comment: Could you guys give me some examples ?

Comment: @JekasG What sort of example are you looking for?

Comment: @JohnDouma Notice that the OP has a 3x3 matrix, so is using homogeneous coordinates which allows affine transformations of the plane to be represented as 3x3 matrices. So, any reflection about any line—not just those through the origin—can be realized as a matrix.

Comment: The matrices displayed in the images you’ve linked to clearly have specific values of $m$ and $c$. Please update your question to include those.

Comment: It looks to me like you’ve gotten the sequence of primitive matrices backwards. Remember that they’re going to left-multiply the vector, so the first one to be applied should be at the right side of the sequence. In general, when you’re having sign problems like these when composing transformations, check to see that you’ve got them in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the matrix of the reflection through the line $y=mx$, above. To get the reflection through $y=mx+c$, translate to the origin, reflect by $M$, and then translate back: $$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1}M\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -c \\ 0 & 0 & 1} 
= \pmatrix{
  \frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} & \frac{2m}{1+m^2} & -\frac{2mc}{1+m^2} \\
  \frac{2m}{1+m^2} & -\frac{1-m^2}{1+m^2} & \frac{2c}{1+m^2} \\
  0 & 0 & 1}.
$$ With $m=\frac12$ and $c=2$, this yields the *Expected Answer*.